# How to mark items as junk in The Outer Worlds?

Tags: windows-10, windows, the-outer-worlds

[image: The Outer Worlds, Mark items as Junk]

> Items you've marked as Junk can be sold in bulk.

Okay, so how do I mark items as junk? There is no UI in the game or anything else, just a tip that *suggests* that you can mark items as junk.

PC / Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... you can not mark items as junk while interacting with a merchant or vending machine. You have to go in to your inventory directly and *then* you press `z`.

It's indirect which means you have to go through your inventory first and then to vendors each time you go to a new area with new item drops.